# fail on CREATE DATABASE graphite WITH OWNER graphite

Tags: postgresql, linux

we have PostgreSQL DB on our Linux server

when we run the following CLI :

```
psql -c 'CREATE DATABASE graphite WITH OWNER graphite'
```

we get:

```
psql: FATAL:  no pg_hba.conf entry for host "[local]", user "root", database "root", SSL off
```

and we set this in `/var/lib/pgsql/data/pg_hba.conf`

```
local   all     graphite                                md5
```

What is the problem here?

Answer (score 0):

I presume that you run this command as `root`. Since you do not specify the user that you use to connect to PostgreSQL the `psql` command assumes that you use your OS user. This user is unknown to PostgreSQL.

Connect yourself with `postgres` (that 'owns' the PostgreSQL processes) and run the same command again. Now it should run correctly if you already created the `graphite` user or role in PostgreSQL.